# object interaction: Calculation on geometric shape

Tags: java, methods

So basically I have this question:
1)Square, a subclass of Rectangle, containing a constructor(with a parameter for the length of a side) and methods that invoke the methods of the Rectangle class to determine the perimeter and area of a square.

So far I have this for the square class

```
class sqaure extends rectangle
{
  public Square(double size)
 {
   super(size, size)
 }
}
```

and this for the rectangle class

```
class rectangle extends Shape
{
  private double length; 
  private double width; 

  public rectangle (double length, double width)
  {
    this.length = length; 
    this.width = width;
  }
  double area()
  {
    return length * width;
  }
  double perimeter()
  {
    return 2.0 * (width + length);
  }
}
```

I need help on the part where it says I need to invoke the method of the rectangle class to determine the perimeter and area of a square.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First of all, all class names, by convention, need to be capitalized.

Also, you don't need to write any additional code: just initialize the square and call the methods on that.

```
Square s = new Square(50d);
double area = s.area();
double perimeter = s.perimeter();
```

or just `override` the area and perimeter methods and return super methods in the square class:

```
double area(){
    return super.area();
}
double perimeter(){
    return super.perimeter();
}
```

the latter is useful if you need to do extra calculations specifically for the square class, but in this example, you don't need it.

Comment: I think your first approach is better.  Overriding here does not make sense as we are not augmenting the implementation in the Rectangle class.

Comment: As I said, you don't need it unless you are doing extra calculations that are square specific

Comment: @Sid also, the op mentioned to write methods that invoke the rectangle class' method, so I wrote one to demonstrate that this is how you do it

Comment: absolutely fine, your approach isn't incorrect at all, just that the first one is almost a perfect one.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should try to follow the naming standards for java classes by starting with a capital letter.

```
Square mySquare = new Square(10.0);
double theArea = mySquare.area();
double thePerimeter = mySquare.perimeter();
```

These calls to `area()` and `perimeter()` are using the implementations in `Rectangle` simply because they have not been overridden in `Square`.